# Is it possible to have a site blog at mydomain.com and your heroku app at app.mydomain.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku

I need to create the sales site for my application in wordpress as their themes are far more impressive than anything I could create in rails in a short time period. I need the rails app to be on a subdomain such as app.mydomain.com and Id prefer to host with heroku.

Is this possible and if so how?

If not what do other app providers do for their sales site and blog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find your answer here: http://docs.heroku.com/custom-domains

The doc is good and the video explains how to customize your DNS. You'll be able to point your DNS wherever you want.

EDIT 1

Far more easier:

- Go to your DNS provider
- add a CNAME for app.mydomain.com
- make it point to your Heroku's URL.